# why bottle does not show the page I returned?

Tags: python, python-requests, bottle

I am new to bottle. I have searched for the answer but could not get any.

Is there anyway to load a page without `redirect`?

The code is like this:

```
from bottle import get, run, template

@get('/list/item')
def listItems():
    r = requests.get('my/url/which/works/')
    return r.content

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(host='localhost', port=8080 )
```

and the webpage is empty. I have also tried `return r.text`, `return template(r.content)`, `return str(r.content)`, `return str(r.content.decode('utf-8'))`, and

```
nf = urllib.urlopen('my/url/whick/works')
return nf.read()
```

none of them returns the page I want.

However, if I write this `return r.content[0]`, it works. the page will show the first letter, which is '<'. But if I write `return r.content[0:100]`, it returns a empty page again.

If I run the requests in command line, this is what it returns:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('my/url/which/works/')
>>>
>>> r.content
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> \n<body copyright="...>\n</body>\n'
```

Is that possible that anyone can help about this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you inspected what you really get in `r.content` ?

Comment: When you say you're url works, what do you mean?  Works in a browser?  Requests is going to get the html for the page, it's not going to get all the other stuff needed to render the page like images, js that isn't inline, etc.

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers, yes, it is a xml data string, as shown below: 

>>> r.content
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> \n<body copyright="......>\n</body>\n'

Comment: @Mateo It is a xml data string that is returned by the url. I have edited the question. Do you mean that the xml is not loaded by bottle? Thank you very much.

Comment: Then it's probably "working."  Start your script, open a browser and goto your page.  If it's blank, right click and inspect (assuming you are using Chrome).  I'm just guessing, but i bet your data is there.

Comment: @Mateo, yes, it is there. but is there anyway to make it show on the webpage? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't specify what you expect to see when your code works as expected, but this may help you:

```
from bottle import get, run, template, response

@get('/list/item')
def listItems():
    r = requests.get('my/url/which/works/')
    response.content_type = 'text/plain'  # added this
    return r.content

...
```

The only change is that your webserver will now be setting the content type of the response to `text/plain`, which should make your browser render the page.

Longer term, if (as I'm inferring from your question) you intend to return XML responses, then I suggest either installing a browser plugin ([here's an example](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xv-%E2%80%94-xml-viewer/eeocglpgjdpaefaedpblffpeebgmgddk?hl=en)), or, better yet, use `curl` or `wget` to see the precise response. This will help you debug your server's responses.

Comment: Wonderful, happy to help. And welcome to StackOverflow! If you found that my answer solved your problem, please mark it as "accepted." Thanks!